# i3 won't load layout (parse error: client cancelled parse via callback return value)

Tags: unix, archlinux

I saved the layout for my workspace and tried to load it following the docs:

```
i3-save-tree --workspace 1 >   /home/goldenoctopus/custom_system_files/workspace-1.json
```

and:

```
i3-msg "workspace 1; append_layout /home/goldenoctopus/custom_system_files/workspace-1.json"
```

But the command have no effect and just return the following error:

```
    ERROR: Your command: (null)
    ERROR:               (null)
    ERROR: parse error: client cancelled parse via callback return value
                                   }                             ]
                 (right here) ------^

    [{"success":true},{"success":false,"error":"parse error: client cancelled parse via callback return value\n                                        }                             ]\n                     (right here) ------^\n"}]
```

Comment: You need to manually edit the layout file to define the swallow criteria. Please have a look at the documentation on layout restoring.

Comment: @IngoBürk, there really is a bug with `append_layout`: you may have swallow criteria set and still get errors.

Comment: That's a very unspecific and general statement to which I cannot reply meaningfully. If there's a bug, please file a bug report and we'll look at it.

Answer (score 1):

There are three things to check and two things to check when you invoke `i3-msg append_layout`, since there seems to be a server bug here.

In the layout file:

- Check there are no remaining comments (invalid JSON)
- Check there are no commas next to any last element of a sequence (invalid JSON)
- Check there are swallow criteria for the panes (required to set‑up the layout)

Point #2 means you have to check you do not left any extra comment when removing commented lines in the swallow criteria in an file generated by `i3-save-tree`.

Then, check you invoke `i3-msg append_layout <path-to-file>` either:

- Using an absolute path for the layout file path
- Invoke `i3-msg append_layout <path-to-file>` from your home directory

Note I got i3 crash box when loading some layout files, which suggest there are severe bug there (at least with i3 version 4.14).